# Installing SSRS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

**"Install and configure"** radio button is disabled for me when installing Reportin Services. Can anybody explain why?

P.S. Using SQL Server 2012, Standard Edition.

Comment: Are you adding features to an existing installation?

Comment: Yes, on existing SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is explained in [Reporting Services Configuration Options (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms144292(v=sql.120).aspx), though it's really impossible to tell what the specific issue is in your case.

From the article:

> Install and configure Installs a report server instance in Native Mode
>   using the default values for the report server databases, service
>   account, and URL reservations. When you choose this option, the report
>   server instance is ready to use when Setup is finished. Setup creates
>   the report server database using a local Database Engine instance, and
>   configures a report server to use default values.
>
> **This option is available only if the default values used in a report
>   server installation are valid for your system**. This option is
>   recommended for developers who want to install all components locally,
>   and for users who are evaluating the software.

(Emphasis added)

So there is something in your environment that is preventing this option. To investigate, the article suggests:

> To view information about the default Settings that Setup uses, or to
>   find out why the default configuration cannot be installed, click
>   **Details**.

It also suggests looking at [What is the Default Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms143711(sql.110).aspx#bkmk_whatisdefaultconfiguration) to help get more details.

You will need to review all this information in your own environment to get your specific issue.